# Salesforce Custom Object Query - REST

Tags: database, rest, object, salesforce

I was just wondering if there is a Salesforce url I could query to return only custom objects. I know that you can get all objects using this url:

```
/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/
```

However, I don't know the url to just get custom objects, if one exists at all. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Force.com Rest API works exactly equal for Custom or Standard objects.

Try this:

```
/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/MyCustomObjectName__c
```

`MyCustomObjectName__c` should be the **API object name** instead standard name.

Comment: Is there any way to get a list of custom object names using rest though? Like a query statements to get a list of all of the custom objects in the database?

Comment: /vXX.X/sobjects/  Lists the available objects and their metadata for your organization's data.

Comment: This does not answer what Adam asked.